# GoJS expanding and collapsing tree nodes

Tags: javascript, charts, tree, expand, gojs

I'm a new in Gojs, and this question is about the node expandind control in tree model.

I just wonder can I control the root node in different way to the other node in tree model.

Take the Gojs official code for example:

```
  $(go.Node, "Horizontal",
    $(go.Panel, "Auto",
      $(go.Shape, "Ellipse", { fill: null }),
      $(go.TextBlock,
        new go.Binding("text", "key"))
    ),
    $("TreeExpanderButton")
  );

diagram.layout = $(go.TreeLayout);

var nodeDataArray = [
  { key: "Alpha" }, { key: "Beta" }, { key: "Gamma" }, { key: "Delta" },
  { key: "Epsilon" }, { key: "Zeta" }, { key: "Eta" }, { key: "Theta" }
];
var linkDataArray = [
  { from: "Alpha", to: "Beta" },
  { from: "Beta", to: "Gamma" },
  { from: "Beta", to: "Delta" },
  { from: "Alpha", to: "Epsilon" },
  { from: "Epsilon", to: "Zeta" },
  { from: "Epsilon", to: "Eta" },
  { from: "Epsilon", to: "Theta" }
];
diagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(nodeDataArray, linkDataArray);
```

and we will get the tree like[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jso9M.png)

How can I remove the treeExpanderButton on the root node only,
and keep the root node be expanded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the predefined "TreeExpanderButton" automatically becomes visible or invisible *only* based on whether there are any links to any child nodes.

So one solution is to copy the definition of "TreeExpanderButton" from extensions/Buttons.js and remove the Binding of the button's **GraphObject.visible** property that depends on the **Node.isTreeLeaf** property.  That will allow us to implement our own scheme for determining the **Node.visible** property, which in this case can be done by implementing **Node.linkConnected** and **Node.linkDisconnected** event handlers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Minimal GoJS Sample</title>
  <!-- Copyright 1998-2022 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width:100%; height:600px"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/gojs"></script>
  <script id="code">
// copied from extensions/Buttons.js so that we can remove the predefined
// binding on the "visible" property.
go.GraphObject.defineBuilder('TreeExpanderButton', function (args) {
  var button = /** @type {Panel} */ (
    go.GraphObject.make('Button',
      { // set these values for the isTreeExpanded binding conversion
        '_treeExpandedFigure': 'MinusLine',
        '_treeCollapsedFigure': 'PlusLine'
      },
      go.GraphObject.make(go.Shape,  // the icon
        {
          name: 'ButtonIcon',
          figure: 'MinusLine',  // default value for isTreeExpanded is true
          stroke: '#424242',
          strokeWidth: 2,
          desiredSize: new go.Size(8, 8)
        },
        // bind the Shape.figure to the Node.isTreeExpanded value using this converter:
        new go.Binding('figure', 'isTreeExpanded',
          function (exp, shape) {
            var but = shape.panel;
            return exp ? but['_treeExpandedFigure'] : but['_treeCollapsedFigure'];
          }
        ).ofObject()
      ),
      // assume initially not visible because there are no links coming out
      { visible: false }
      // NOTE: removed the Binding on "visible" depending on Node.isTreeLeaf
    )
  );

  // tree expand/collapse behavior
  button.click = function (e, btn) {
    var node = btn.part;
    if (node instanceof go.Adornment) node = node.adornedPart;
    if (!(node instanceof go.Node)) return;
    var diagram = node.diagram;
    if (diagram === null) return;
    var cmd = diagram.commandHandler;
    if (node.isTreeExpanded) {
      if (!cmd.canCollapseTree(node)) return;
    } else {
      if (!cmd.canExpandTree(node)) return;
    }
    e.handled = true;
    if (node.isTreeExpanded) {
      cmd.collapseTree(node);
    } else {
      cmd.expandTree(node);
    }
  };

  return button;
});

const $ = go.GraphObject.make;

const myDiagram =
  $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
    {
      layout: $(go.TreeLayout),
      "undoManager.isEnabled": true
    });

myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
  $(go.Node, "Horizontal",
    $(go.Panel, "Auto",
      $(go.Shape, { fill: "white" },
        new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
      $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 8 },
        new go.Binding("text"))
    ),
    $("TreeExpanderButton", { name: "BUTTON" }),
    {
      linkConnected: (node, link, port) => node.findObject("BUTTON").visible = node.findTreeChildrenLinks().count > 0 && node.findTreeParentLink() !== null,
      linkDisconnected: (node, link, port) => node.findObject("BUTTON").visible = node.findTreeChildrenLinks().count > 0 && node.findTreeParentLink() !== null
    }
  );

myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
[
  { key: 1, text: "Alpha", color: "lightblue" },
  { key: 2, text: "Beta", color: "orange" },
  { key: 3, text: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen" },
  { key: 4, text: "Delta", color: "pink" },
  { key: 5, text: "Epsilon", color: "yellow" }
],
[
  { from: 1, to: 2 },
  { from: 1, to: 3 },
  { from: 3, to: 4 },
  { from: 3, to: 5 }
]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I figured up another way to solve it after that.
I just add an category to distinguish root and the others.
And used it to make different template to build the tree nodes.